# Is a hostname guaranteed to be a valid Windows directory name?

Tags: windows, directory, hostname

I've read through [Valid characters of a hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523028/valid-characters-of-a-hostname) and the relevant wiki pages.  What I haven't been able to ascertain is, if I'm on a Windows machine with an extended hostname, will gethostname() return a ToAscii version of the name, or the UTF8 string?

And more importantly can

```
gethostname(buffer,LEN);
mkdir(buffer, mode);
```

ever fail due to an invalid name?

Comment: "Failure is always an option." If gethostname/mkdir doesn't fail because of the name, it may still fail for another reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some [useful information on hostnames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN in terms of the DNS hostname and the NetBIOS hostname.  It seems to suggest that the hostname may indeed be UTF-8, but it's not decisive.

So if you get UTF-8 from gethostname, you'll probably have to convert it to UTF-16 (or the system default codepage) in order to call any Windows function that makes a directory.  Also note that different filesystems have different rules for the character set.  NTFS will handle Unicode pretty gracefully, but FAT won't.

You could try changing your local machine's name to something with non-ASCII characters (and perhaps even some characters that aren't in the system default codepage).

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a definitive answer, but you gave some good info/ideas, so I'll go ahead and give it to you.  Thanks.