# How to prevent python requests from percent encoding URLs contain semicolon?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to post some data to a url like `http://www.google.com/;id=aaa`
I use follow codes:

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/;id=aaa'
r = requests.post(url, headers=my_headers, data=my_data, timeout=10)
```

Unfortunately, I find `requests` just cut my uri to `http://www.google.com/` without any warning...

Is there some way to pass the the parameters in their original form - without percent encoding?

I try `config={'encode_uri': False}` but it was abandoned, and `urllib.unquote` wasn't useful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean there is a ';' in your target url?

Comment: Why are you using the semi-colon?

Comment: @Acepcs yes... I just use this API.

Comment: What API are you talking about? it makes no sense to have a semi-colon in your url and also requests would error if you passed that url

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes...i don't know why there is a semicolon in his API request...

Comment: It make sense. although I think judge user by semi-colon is silly.., :( I just have to use this API..So, Let's just talk how to deal with it..:)

Comment: Can you add a link to the APIi documentation?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry about it. it's for inner use.

Comment: @Keatinge Thinks but it will add a ? in url .

Comment: Without some documentation it is impossible to answer your question as we have no idea what the server accepts or is expecting.

Comment: This is simply not true. I tested `requests.post(<valid url>)` and got a HTTP OK 200, whereas with `requests.post(<valid url>;id=aaa)` i get a 404 response. So `requests.post` definitely did not ignore the `;id=aaa` part. I even got a message saying `<valid url>;id=aaa was not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 2616, section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2) specifies the syntax of an HTTP URL as:

```
http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

It also says:

> If the abs_path is not present in the URL, it MUST be given as "/" when
> used as a Request-URI for a resource

In this URL:

```
http://www.google.com;id=aaa
```

there is no `/`, so there is no `abs_path` and there is no `:`, so there is no `port`. It means that `www.google.com;id=aaa` is hostname.

Semicolons are not allowed in hostnames (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523068/389289) for what is allowed in hostname), so this **URL is invalid**.

This would be a valid URL, if `id=aaa` should be part of the path:

```
http://www.google.com/;id=aaa
```

This also, if `id=aaa` should be part of the query:

```
http://www.google.com/?;id=aaa
```

## EDIT

The question has been modified to ask about `http://www.google.com/;id=aaa` instead.

That URL is valid, and as far as I was able to test it, [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) handles it without any problems.

Comment: e...(๑Ő௰Ő๑)I am sorry ..the URL should be http://www.google.com/;id=aaa

Comment: post data is sent in the body of the request not as a query so `http://www.google.com/?;id=aaa` would not make any sense unless there are also query params expected .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham A query is a bit awkward in the context of an HTTP POST, but I believe it is legal and should be supported.

Comment: It is valid but according to the OP not what is happening here. The question in not answerable as the OP has not furnished any documentation so only he/she knows what is expected from the API.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, well, this aswered the original question. Now that the question has been "fixed", I believe it has no answer. Probably the problem is on the server side, which we do not see.