# How to check whether hostname is domain name in Go?

Tags: validation, go, hostname, domain-name

How can I check whether [URL.Hostname](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Hostname) is a valid domain name? I am searching for the exact same behaviour as [URI.CheckHostName](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.uri.checkhostname) in the .NET framework.

Comment: Currently, there is no solution using standard library only. You need to use third party library/regex. However, if you need to support *internationalized domain name*, the task may not trivial. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523028/valid-characters-of-a-hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523028/valid-characters-of-a-hostname)

Answer (score 5):

You could use idna, kind of, to check on this.

```
import  "golang.org/x/net/idna"
h, err := idna.Lookup.ToASCII("example.com")
fmt.Println(h, err)
```

Also see;

- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20.5/src/net/dnsclient.go#L72-L75
- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.20.5/src/net/http/cookie.go#L329-L333

Answer (score 3):

See my code [here](https://gist.github.com/chmike/d4126a3247a6d9a70922fc0e8b4f4013).

The function checks if the provided domain name is valid relative to the rules. It doesn't check if the domain name exist.

Answer (score 0):

The function [IsDNSName](https://godoc.org/github.com/asaskevich/govalidator#IsDNSName) from the `govalidator` package should do what you want. For details on installing it, see the [README](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: It allows underscore in domain names which is wrong. See RFC1034 section 3.5. A later change to this RFC is to allow digits as first label character. The TLD label can't start with a digit to avoid confusion between domain names and IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dchest/validator

func ValidateDomainByResolvingIt(domain string) error
ValidateDomainByResolvingIt queries DNS for the given domain name, and returns nil if the the name resolves, or an error.