# URL Api: Handling of white spaces in URLs

Tags: javascript, url

When testing the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API, I noticed a difference in the handling of URLs with white spaces on different browsers:

```js
console.log(new URL('https://a b').host)
```

In Firefox, it will throw an error:

```
TypeError: https://a b is not a valid URL.
```

But on other browsers, it will accept the URL and print `a%20b`. For instance, Brave, Opera, and Chrome.

The implementations seem to agree that white spaces in the pathname are valid, and they will automatically quote them:

```js
console.log(new URL('https://a/b c').pathname)
```

Prints `/b%20c` on all implementations that I tested.

**Questions:**

- Is it correct that spaces in the host name and in the pathname are valid?
- Does the same logic also apply for other space-like characters (e.g., tabs)?
- Is it just a bug in Firefox, or are there more browsers that will interpret white spaces differently?

**Update:** Chromium 70.0.3521.2 started to reject it, while Chrome 69.0.3497.42 still accepts it.

Comment: How about call `encodeURI()` first before putting anything in `URL()`?

Comment: @WilliamChong I wanted to use the URL API to detect whether some text could be an URL (e.g., "example.com") or is just some text. An idea was to test whether "https://<text>" is a valid URL. But if white spaces are allowed, this approach will not work, as almost any random text will pass that check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), "No blank or space characters are permitted as part of a name." (referring to a "Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name"). I believe that the particular rule is current (as of 2018) regarding this, so it looks like Firefox is enforcing this, while the other browsers are more permissive.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523068

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a look at the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), you'll find that there are limited characters that are valid at all in URLs, and no space characters (tabs or spaces) are among them.

The auto-replacing you're seeing is a browser thing to help the user.

Comment: The closest what I see in the RFC is this: "In some cases, extra whitespace (spaces, linebreaks, tabs, etc.) may need to be added to break long URLs across lines. The whitespace  should be ignored when extracting the URL." Sounds a bit vague, but at least it is some argument for treating "http://a b" as a legal URL. Maybe the browsers are right to accept it.

Comment: No, there's a list of acceptable characters. The line you're talking about is when printing URLs in eg word documents

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `encodeURI()`:

```js
console.log(new URL(encodeURI('https://a b')).host);
```

For more details, see [MDN Docs on JavaScript's `encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).