# Getting 404 Not Found error message when trying to push a Java application to Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, push, cloud-foundry

I've been deploying a Java application and trying to push it to the Cloud using the PaaS Cloud Foundry but it seems like one of the routes can't be accessed when I am trying to push my application.
Also, I am using Anynines (https://www.anynines.com/) for the Cloud Foundry part (and I checked, this is not an authentication problem).
The exact error log I get when putting the verbose mode on is :

```
REQUEST: [2020-07-27T14:48:16+02:00]
GET /v2/routes/reserved/domain/21d14133-2acd-462e-84ff-2a0d56bbd9ae?host=logicielgestionformations HTTP/1.1
Host: api.de.a9s.eu
Accept: application/json
Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]
User-Agent: cf/6.51.0+2acd15650.2020-04-07 (go1.13.8; amd64 windows)

RESPONSE: [2020-07-27T14:48:16+02:00]
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 86
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2020 12:48:15 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 5eb75dbe-96ec-40df-61ec-ac37b158d47c::5a0552f3-22cb-4c76-b234-c72b29010a1e
{
  "code": 10000,
  "description": "Unknown request",
  "error_code": "CF-NotFound"
}
```

I've been searching everywhere I could to get an answer to my problem but no one seems to have the same as me...
If you could help me that would be extremely nice of you :)

EDIT :

I have found the problem, I only had to remove the "-" at the beginning of my manifest.yml, as it was written here : https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html (**Note: If your app name begins with the dash character (-), you cannot interact with the app using the cf CLI. This is because the cf CLI interprets the dash as a flag**).

Now I have another problem to solve though : it seems like I have to choose a buildpack...

`Error staging application: An app was not successfully detected by any available buildpack`

Regards,
Déborah Jabès

Comment: What's the full push command and full verbose output of `cf push`?

Comment: push command is `cf push <app_name> -v` but the full verbose of the output is really long... I don't know whether I can put it here

Comment: If it won't fit here, stash it somewhere else like a Gist and link to it. Really need to see the full output. If you have a `manifest.yml` file, include that also.

Comment: I created a gist, here's the link : https://gist.github.com/deborah-jabes/9629585ac14bb6c4a31a28b93b3c5254

Comment: I don't think it's your problem, but you can't set `memory: 64MB` for a Java app. Most Java apps are going to need at least 1G of memory. You can do less in some circumstances but it will likely require you to do some additional tuning of memory settings. Setting `buildpack: none` is also likely to create issues for you later. If you're trying to unset the buildpack, I believe you want `buildpack: null` but that's older syntax, I haven't tried it but `buildpacks: []` is probably the more modern variation.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but I think your issue might with the hostname you've chosen. it has `_` characters which are not technically allowed in a hostname (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523068/1585136). It kind of looks like it's trying to strip the `_` out, which might be confusing things. Try switching to a `-`, which is an allowed character, or camel case and see if that works better.

Comment: I modified my manifest as you told me to, but I can't see a way to change my hostname as my provider is Anynines...

Comment: You have `host: logiciel_gestion_formations` set in your manifest. Change it there or override it with `cf push -n <new-host-name>`. As an aside, you might be better off deleting your app and repushing with the new hostname. That will give you a fresh app and remove all server side state.

Comment: I changed the app name as well as the host name in my manifest to **logicielGestionFormations** but it doesn't work better, I still have the 404 Not Found error in verbose mode. (Thank you for helping me, by the way)

Comment: Ok, can you give me an updated trace log?

Comment: I updated my gist with the new manifest and trace log : https://gist.github.com/deborah-jabes/9629585ac14bb6c4a31a28b93b3c5254

Comment: OK,  not sure if this is a copy & paste error, but your manifest.yml is not valid yaml. You've got tab characters in there and it should have spaces. Can you double check that your manifest.yml is valid yaml? http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Nm, I see. You found it. The name you used had an invalid character. You should udpate and add an answer.

Comment: My yml is a valid yaml, according to the link you provided me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, I only had to remove the "-" at the beginning of my manifest.yml, as it was written here : https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html (**Note: If your app name begins with the dash character (-), you cannot interact with the app using the cf CLI. This is because the cf CLI interprets the dash as a flag**).