# How can I escape a colon in an Ansible host name?

Tags: ansible

The colon `:` is a special character in an [ansible playbook `hosts` value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) that indicates separation in a list of hostname match patterns. I would like to have a host with a `:` in the name. Is there a way to escape the `:` in the `hosts` field so that it will be interpreted as one name?

Ex in my playbook yaml file:

```
- name: Do stuff
  hosts: "my:host"
...
```

This will be interpreted as 2 hosts named `my` and `host`, but I'd like to have it be interpreted as one host named `my:host`.

Comment: And even if that would be possible it would result into an invalid hostname. Please have a look into [valid characters of a hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523068/6771046). If you like to have such similar pattern you may name it `my.host.local`, `my.router.local`, etc.

Comment: If there is a really a need for special character URL you may have a look into Ansible Issue [#11572](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11572) and `.encode('punycode')` or `.decode('punycode')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accommodate patterns containing IPv6 addresses Ansible allows `,` as an alternate separator:

```
- name: Do stuff
  hosts: my:host,
```

However, your life will be easier if you just use valid hostnames instead of trying to work out ways of addressing invalid ones.

Comment: This works, thanks! I agree that this naming convention is strange. This is just an old naming convention for instances at my org. In this case I am using `add_host` to add the host dynamically and giving it a different name than the address that Ansible is actually connecting to via SSH.